# Spring MVC application doesnt mapping. Apache TomCat 9. IntelliJ IDEA. Linux Mint

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, tomcat, intellij-idea

****I just started learning how to make Spring MVC applications. Installed Tomcat 9. The error is most likely that the mapping does not work. Also i use thymeleaf. The execution of the program basically does not reach my Java code (I set breakpoints and the application did not stop).****

> I have tried installing different versions of Tomcat

I also checked the port and entered the correct URL. I would also like to note that when entering the full path to the hello.html file (relative to the webapp), in my case *http://localhost:8080/views/hello.html*, it also gives a 404 error, but everything will work with the jsp file *http://localhost:8080/views/hello.jsp* (but it's still not the right thing, because the mapping doesn't work).

> As planned, hello.html should be displayed in the browser when you
> enter the string *http://localhost:8080/helloW* in the url.

The problem is that when I type in the URL ***http://localhost:8080/helloW*** and see:
[image]

I also tried to put different Application Context in the configuration:
[image]

My project structure:

[image]

Below i going to show code of my classes:

HelloController:

```java
    package edu.vega.spring;
    
    import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
    
    @Controller
    public class HelloController {
        @GetMapping(value = {"/helloW", "/"})
        public String sayHello(){
            return "hello";
        }
    }
```

MySpringMVCDispatcherServletInitializer:

```java
    package edu.vega.spring.config;
    
    import org.springframework.web.servlet.support.AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer;
    
    public class MySpringMVCDispatcherServletInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {
    
        @Override
        protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
            return null;
        }
    
        @Override
        protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
            return new Class[] {SpringConfig.class};
        }
    
        @Override
        protected String[] getServletMappings() {
            return new String[]{"/"};
        }
    }
```

SpringConfig:

```java
    package edu.vega.spring.config;
    
    import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
    import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
    import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
    import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
    import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
    import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
    import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.ViewResolverRegistry;
    import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurer;
    import org.thymeleaf.spring5.SpringTemplateEngine;
    import org.thymeleaf.spring5.templateresolver.SpringResourceTemplateResolver;
    import org.thymeleaf.spring5.view.ThymeleafViewResolver;
    
    @Configuration
    @ComponentScan("edu.vega.spring")
    @EnableWebMvc
    public class SpringConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {
        private final ApplicationContext applicationContext;
    
        @Autowired
        public SpringConfig(ApplicationContext applicationContext) {
            this.applicationContext = applicationContext;
        }
    
        @Bean
        public SpringResourceTemplateResolver templateResolver() {
            SpringResourceTemplateResolver templateResolver = new SpringResourceTemplateResolver();
            templateResolver.setApplicationContext(applicationContext);
            templateResolver.setPrefix("views/");
            templateResolver.setSuffix(".html");
            return templateResolver;
        }
    
        @Bean
        public SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine() {
            SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine = new SpringTemplateEngine();
            templateEngine.setTemplateResolver(templateResolver());
            templateEngine.setEnableSpringELCompiler(true);
            return templateEngine;
        }
    
        @Override
        public void configureViewResolvers(ViewResolverRegistry registry) {
            ThymeleafViewResolver resolver = new ThymeleafViewResolver();
            resolver.setTemplateEngine(templateEngine());
            registry.viewResolver(resolver);
        }
    }
```

pom.xml (dependencies):

```xml
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>junit</groupId>
          <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
          <version>3.8.1</version>
          <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
          <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
          <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
          <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
          <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.thymeleaf</groupId>
          <artifactId>thymeleaf-spring5</artifactId>
          <version>3.1.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
    
        <dependency>
          <groupId>jakarta.servlet</groupId>
          <artifactId>jakarta.servlet-api</artifactId>
          <version>6.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
    
      </dependencies>
      <build>
        <finalName>spring_web_app1</finalName>
      </build>
    </project>
```

I tried a lot of things, but it doesn’t work, I’m already thinking about completely changing the OS to Ubuntu and maybe then it will help.

All logs that i have (now i in Access Log):

[image]

Output:

```
    127.0.0.1 - - [07/Jul/2023:11:30:41 +0300] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 48
127.0.0.1 - - [07/Jul/2023:11:30:41 +0300] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 48
0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 - - [07/Jul/2023:11:30:41 +0300] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 48
0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 - - [07/Jul/2023:11:30:47 +0300] "GET /helloW HTTP/1.1" 404 682
```

LocalHost log output:

```
07-Jul-2023 11:30:40.491 INFO [RMI TCP Connection(2)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log Marking servlet [dispatcher] as unavailable
07-Jul-2023 11:30:40.492 SEVERE [RMI TCP Connection(2)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup Servlet [dispatcher] in web application [] threw load() exception
    java.lang.ClassCastException: class org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet cannot be cast to class javax.servlet.Servlet (org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet is in unnamed module of loader org.apache.catalina.loader.ParallelWebappClassLoader @168986bb; javax.servlet.Servlet is in unnamed module of loader java.net.URLClassLoader @3aeaafa6)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1020)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:960)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:4673)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:4980)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:683)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:658)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:662)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.manageApp(HostConfig.java:1782)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:578)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:294)
        at java.management/com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:803)
        at java.management/com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:802)
        at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:460)
        at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:408)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:578)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:294)
        at java.management/com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:803)
        at java.management/com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:802)
        at java.management/com.sun.jmx.remote.security.MBeanServerAccessController.invoke(MBeanServerAccessController.java:472)
        at java.management.rmi/javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1472)
        at java.management.rmi/javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl$PrivilegedOperation.run(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1310)
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:714)
        at java.management.rmi/javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doPrivilegedOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1412)
        at java.management.rmi/javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.invoke(RMIConnectionImpl.java:829)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:578)
        at java.rmi/sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:360)
        at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:200)
        at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:197)
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:714)
        at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:196)
        at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:598)
        at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:844)
        at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$0(TCPTransport.java:721)
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:400)
        at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:720)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1144)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:642)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1623)
```

Exception with Tomcat 10+

```
12-Jul-2023 13:32:02.151 SEVERE [RMI TCP Connection(2)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log Servlet.init() for servlet [dispatcher] threw exception
    java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'void org.springframework.web.context.support.ServletContextResourceLoader.<init>(jakarta.servlet.ServletContext)'
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:155)
        at jakarta.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:143)
        at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.init(HttpServlet.java:121)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:944)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:901)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:805)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:4633)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:4926)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:683)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:658)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:713)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.manageApp(HostConfig.java:1821)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:578)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:294)
        at java.management/com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:803)
        at java.management/com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:802)
        at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:428)
        at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:376)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:578)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:294)
        at java.management/com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:803)
        at java.management/com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:802)
        at java.management/com.sun.jmx.remote.security.MBeanServerAccessController.invoke(MBeanServerAccessController.java:472)
        at java.management.rmi/javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1472)
        at java.management.rmi/javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl$PrivilegedOperation.run(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1310)
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:714)
        at java.management.rmi/javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doPrivilegedOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1412)
        at java.management.rmi/javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.invoke(RMIConnectionImpl.java:829)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:578)
        at java.rmi/sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:360)
        at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:200)
        at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:197)
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:714)
        at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:196)
        at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:598)
        at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:844)
        at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$0(TCPTransport.java:721)
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:400)
        at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:720)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1144)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:642)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1623)
12-Jul-2023 13:32:02.151 SEVERE [RMI TCP Connection(2)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup Servlet [dispatcher] in web application [] threw load() exception
    java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'void org.springframework.web.context.support.ServletContextResourceLoader.<init>(jakarta.servlet.ServletContext)'
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:155)
        at jakarta.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:143)
        at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.init(HttpServlet.java:121)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:944)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:901)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:805)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:4633)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:4926)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:683)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:658)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:713)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.manageApp(HostConfig.java:1821)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:578)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:294)
        at java.management/com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:803)
        at java.management/com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:802)
        at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:428)
        at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:376)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:578)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:294)
        at java.management/com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:803)
        at java.management/com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:802)
        at java.management/com.sun.jmx.remote.security.MBeanServerAccessController.invoke(MBeanServerAccessController.java:472)
        at java.management.rmi/javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1472)
        at java.management.rmi/javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl$PrivilegedOperation.run(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1310)
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:714)
        at java.management.rmi/javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doPrivilegedOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1412)
        at java.management.rmi/javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.invoke(RMIConnectionImpl.java:829)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:578)
        at java.rmi/sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:360)
        at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:200)
        at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:197)
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:714)
        at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:196)
        at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:598)
        at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:844)
        at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$0(TCPTransport.java:721)
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:400)
        at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:720)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1144)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:642)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1623)
```

Exception with spring5 and thymeleaf5

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.thymeleaf.spring5.view.ThymeleafViewResolver#0' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContextMVC.xml]: Error setting property values; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.NotWritablePropertyException: Invalid property 'debug' of bean class [org.thymeleaf.spring5.view.ThymeleafViewResolver]: Bean property 'debug' is not writable or has an invalid setter method. Does the parameter type of the setter match the return type of the getter?
```

My pom.xml with openJDK 20:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>edu.vega.spring</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring_web_app1</artifactId>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>spring_web_app1 Maven Webapp</name>
  <url>https://maven.apache.org</url>
  <properties>
    <maven.compiler.source>20</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>20</maven.compiler.target>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.13.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
      <version>6.0.11</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
      <version>6.0.11</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
      <version>6.0.11</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
      <version>6.0.11</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.thymeleaf</groupId>
      <artifactId>thymeleaf-spring6</artifactId>
      <version>3.1.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.thymeleaf</groupId>
      <artifactId>thymeleaf</artifactId>
      <version>3.1.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>jakarta.servlet</groupId>
      <artifactId>jakarta.servlet-api</artifactId>
      <version>6.0.0</version>
    </dependency>

  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <finalName>spring_web_app1</finalName>
  </build>
</project>
```

Error log with pom.xml above (sorry for screenshot but 30k symbols limit in body):
[image]

Comment: What does the logging show? You could set the logging level for spring very low to see what is happening internally.

Comment: @LeonKlute i have edited question. What kind of log did u mean exactly?

Comment: Hey, quick question. Is there a particular reason you're not using Spring Boot?

Comment: @alvonellos sorry, but my spring knowledge is so little and all that i know, i training spring MVC for web apps and do this

Comment: @alvonellos or you told about dependencies?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, in 1 week i solve my problem and i hope if someone take a same problem my answer help you.

All dependencies in pom.xml was right (jakarta-api 6 with spring6 and thymeleaf6) ofc i need use TomCat 10+ for Spring 6+ (10.1.11 - currently my version).

I tried use `mvn clean install` command in the terminal and i see that problem:

```
Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-war-plugin:2.2:war 
(default-war) on project spring_web_app1: Execution default-war of goal 
org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-war-plugin:2.2:war failed: Unable to load 
the mojo 'war' in the plugin 'org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-war- 
plugin:2.2' due to an API incompatibility:
```

org.codehaus.plexus.component.repository.exception.ComponentLookupException: Cannot access defaults field of Properties

The problem is related to version compatibility of the **Maven War Plugin**.

After that i add plugin with new version:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.3</version>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
```

> Maybe Perhaps the default version was 2.2

And after that if u run use `mvn clean install` u will take an error with web.xml and u need add that file and use basic config (u can find it in google) after configurating web.xml u can use `mvn clean install`.

My full pom.xml:

```
 <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>edu.vega.spring</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring_web_app1</artifactId>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>spring_web_app1 Maven Webapp</name>
  <url>https://maven.apache.org</url>
  <properties>
    <maven.compiler.source>20</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>20</maven.compiler.target>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.13.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
      <version>6.0.11</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
      <version>6.0.11</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
      <version>6.0.11</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
      <version>6.0.11</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.thymeleaf</groupId>
      <artifactId>thymeleaf-spring6</artifactId>
      <version>3.1.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.thymeleaf</groupId>
      <artifactId>thymeleaf</artifactId>
      <version>3.1.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>jakarta.servlet</groupId>
      <artifactId>jakarta.servlet-api</artifactId>
      <version>6.0.0</version>
    </dependency>

  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.3</version>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

> Please correcting me if u will find some mistakes in my answer.

Comment: Hey nice work! Glad you got it resolved. Did you learn anything about spring boot later on?

Comment: @alvonellos Hi, yes a lot of as i suppose :)

Comment: I am so glad! It's a neat framework. I really like it.

Answer (score 1):

> java.lang.ClassCastException: class org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet cannot be cast to class javax.servlet.Servlet (org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet

Spring 6.0 requires the new `jakarta.servlet` namespace instead of `javax.servlet`. So you'll need Tomcat 10, it appears.

https://spring.io/blog/2022/11/16/spring-framework-6-0-goes-ga

https://tomcat.apache.org/migration-10.html

Comment: Yes, but tomcat 10+ doesnt work (i started use tomcat since 10.1) and solution of that problem was change tomcat 10 to tomcat 9, but with tomcat 9 happens problem above. I added exception in my question (log with tomcat 10)

Comment: i tryed use thymeleaf5 nad spring 5 but i got another exception, i added it also

Comment: I guess that's two or three questions, then :-)

Comment: Have you tried a completely consistent combination, though? (Can't tell from your pom.xml, which doesn't show spring.version, but original exception indicates you were trying Spring 6.) e.g. Tomcat 10 with Spring 6 and thymeleaf-spring*6*

Comment: Yes i did it, happens same problem, i found article on RedHat and root cause of my problem its "A class mapped as a Servlet via annotations or in the application WEB-INF/web.xml does not extend Servlet." But this class extends this (i checked it in IDEA in my project)

Article: https://access.redhat.com/solutions/1616883

Comment: Sure i know that Spring 6.0 require jakarta, i tried with jakarta, with javax, with jakarta and javax

Comment: My best guess is still that you have mismatched versions. The various errors indicate missing methods or fields or classes. I suggest posting your full pom.xml and the specific error you get with it.

Comment: i added pom.xml with spring6 (new spring 6.0.11) and jakarta-api 6.0.0

Comment: Thanks for u tried to help me i add answer